# Cannot publish dashboard to PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I've setup a dashboard using Tabular Analysis Services as a data source that sits on virtual machine on Azure. I've setup the same dashboard on both virtual machine and local desktop.

When I click "Publish" I get an error message on both environments:

"Publishing failed for an unknown reason."

Environments:

- My desktop runs Windows 10.
- Virtual Machine runs: Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2016 2.4
- Dashboard was designed using Power BI Desktop.

I do not have any issues connecting to the database.

Please can you advise how to publish dashboard to PowerBI using Analysis Services Tabular on virtual machine.

Comment: Are you sure you can access to Analysis Services from Power BI?. Try create a simple report from Power BI app using Analysis Serices as datasource to be sure you have acess. Also check if you are authenticated from Power BI Desktop app.

Comment: Yes, I've opened the ports and firewall to connect to azure tabular. I also open Data Tools or Power BI Desktop with Azure's account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to AS Tabular servers, you need to be using the Analysis Services connector.  You can read up on that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/03/11/power-bi-analysis-services-connector-deep-dive.aspx